# node.js jade+express table with array of elements

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

I was wondering if the .jade for the files are necessary when invoking with `res.render('login', { locals: { title: 'Hello - Please Login To Your Account' }});`. Assuming login.jade exists. I was also wondering if it is possible to just create an html5 with it. would i have to invoke it like res.render('login.html')?
so after installing html module i got the following in my login page:

```
TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'compile'
    at Function.compile (/var/www/node-login/node_modules/express/lib/view.js:68:33)
    at ServerResponse._render (/var/www/node-login/node_modules/express/lib/view.js:417:18)
    at ServerResponse.render (/var/www/node-login/node_modules/express/lib/view.js:318:17)
    at /var/www/node-login/app/server/router.js:49:8
    at callbacks (/var/www/node-login/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:272:11)
    at param (/var/www/node-login/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:246:11)
    at pass (/var/www/node-login/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:253:5)
    at Router._dispatch (/var/www/node-login/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:280:5)
    at Object.handle (/var/www/node-login/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:45:10)
    at next (/var/www/node-login/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/http.js:204:15)
```

Comment: shouldn't be required. it's not with .ejs

Comment: it gives me the following line when embedded in .jade file directly I'm sorry, the page or resource you are searching for is currently unavailable. i am trying with res.render now